# CSS plagiarism checker

Tags: css, plagiarism-detection

I sell a theme for a well known php web script. The theme that I sell is only CSS, I wrote this CSS code and it's about 700 lines of code.

I'm starting to get the suspicion that people are illegally using my theme so my question is, **is there a website where I can paste my CSS code and it will check other websites for the same CSS code?**

For example, the website **CopyScape.com** will check websites for matching content, but not CSS.

If anyone can help, it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I like this idea! I suppose you'd have to write your own. A robust checker would do a grammatical comparison rather than string matching. Good luck!

Comment: Probably off topic here though. Perhaps http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to search multiple websites for matching or similar code, is a little slow and can be faulted easily.. Say for example, if the css file is generated using PHP and is only visible on a valid / active session..

This would mask the use and ability for someone like google to index it anyway..

Generally people use callback type methods, Say for example... Some where hidden or hard to find... you would have a simple 1 pixel image that is actually a direct/absolute URL to your webserver.

When the image is requested, you have a server side language like PHP grab the requesting URL and log that while still returning the correct 1 pixel image so to them it does not seem obvious what is happening.

As long as somewhere in your template you have a link/script/image/iframe or some other means of requesting a file.. You can catch a few of these people easily..